# Submitting jobs with different parameters using command line databricks

Tags: bash, azure, command-line, databricks

I have jar and an associated properties file. In order to run the jar, this is what I do on Databricks on Azure:

I click on:

```
  +Create Job

      Task: com.xxx.sparkmex.core.ModelExecution in my.jar - Edit / Upload JAR / Remove
      Parameters: Edit
        Main Class: com.xxx.sparkmex.core.ModelExecution
        Arguments: ["-file","/dbfs/mnt/mypath/myPropertyFile.properties","-distributed"]

      Cluster: MyCluster
```

and then I click `RunNow`

I am trying to achive the same using databricks cli

This is what I am doing/want to do:

1) upload the properties file

```
dbfs cp myPropertyFile.properties dbfs:/mnt/mypath/myPropertyFile.properties
```

2) Create a job: `databricks jobs create` when I do this, it asks for a --jason-file. Where do I get the jason file from?

3) Upload the jar file: how do I upload the jar file?

4) Upload the property file: how do I upload the properties file?

5) restart the cluster: `databricks clusters restart --cluster-id MYCLUSTERID`

6) Run the job

and Repeat. The reason I want to repeat is that everytime I upload a new properties file with a different settings.
I do not know how to do step 2 to 4 and step 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For step two, you will need to create the JSON file yourself.  Think of this as your cluster configuration.  [Here's an example](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/examples.html#create-and-run-a-jar-job) that creates a job using a JAR file:

```
{
      "name": "SparkPi JAR job",
      "new_cluster": {
        "spark_version": "5.2.x-scala2.11",
        "node_type_id": "r3.xlarge",
        "aws_attributes": {"availability": "ON_DEMAND"},
        "num_workers": 2
        },
     "libraries": [{"jar": "dbfs:/docs/sparkpi.jar"}],
     "spark_jar_task": {
        "main_class_name":"org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
        "parameters": "10"
        }
}
```

Save that as a JSON file and include it in your API request.  You can also include the JSON directly in the `curl` command.  See the link above for an example of that. You would want to pass `myPropertyFile.properties` as a value to the `"parameters"` key in the JSON.

You can upload the JAR and properties file in the same way you performed step 1 - [the DBFS command group](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html#dbfs-cli) of the Databricks CLI.

```
databricks fs cp /path_to_local_file/myJar.jar dbfs:/path_to_file_on_dbfs/
```

After you create the job and have the job ID, you can use the [`run-now`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/jobs.html#run-now) API to kick it off.

If you want to automate this process and make it repeatable you could write a bash script that takes arguments and makes calls to the CLI.  Alternatively, you could use [wrappers for the CLI in Python](https://github.com/crflynn/databricks-api) or write a Python script to manage the REST API calls yourself.